# How to customize the text on empty cell value using Bootstrap-Vue?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

What I want to achieve is put "-" on every empty cell value. Like this (see the "Name" row):

[image]

How do I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use add a formatter if you use the `fields` prop.
Here you can create a method which either returns your name if there is one, or `-` if there's none.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [
        { key: "name", formatter: 'formatName' },
        { key: "age" }
      ],
      items: [
        { age: 40, name: 'Dickerson Macdonald' },
        { age: 21, name: '' },
        { age: 89, name: 'Geneva Wilson' },
        { age: 38, name: 'Jami Carney'}
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    formatName(value) {
      return value || '-'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields"></b-table>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use `slots` to create the logic in your template, or maybe render something else if there's no name. But if it's simply displaying a `-`, I'd stick with a formatter.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [
        { key: "name" },
        { key: "age" }
      ],
      items: [
        { age: 40, name: 'Dickerson Macdonald' },
        { age: 21, name: '' },
        { age: 89, name: 'Geneva Wilson' },
        { age: 38, name: 'Jami Carney'}
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
    <template #cell(name)="{ value }">
      {{ value || '-' }}
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Gosh this is amazing, it didn't cross in my mind. THANK YOU!. formatter is the best!. I hardly found answer about this. THANK YOU!